# Distribution of transformed variable

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions

I'm given a random variable $X_n$ that is wrt the following measure:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\#\{X_n\in [a, b]\}}{n} = \int_a^b\sin^2\theta d\theta.$$

with an error term $O(\log n / n)$.

Now I'm trying to find the distribution of $\cos^2 X_n$. The text I'm reading says this is $\int_a^b \cos^2 \theta d\theta$, which I'm already not sure of, and I also want to figure out what the error term of this is.

Comment: Notation?  What does # mean here?

Comment: The size of the set $\{X_n \in [a, b]\}$

Comment: Is $(X_n)$ a sequence with some characteristics?

Comment: Problem statement is still unclear.

Comment: $(X_n)$ is a sequence of random variables that distributes according to the measure given, yeah.

Comment: What does "wrt" mean? I suspect it means "with respect to" but you are not saying what $X_n$ is and with respect to what. The error term I guess you mean the difference $\dfrac{\#\{X_n \in [a,b]\}}{n} - \int\limits_a^b \sin^2.$ But then you use the term "error" again and it is completely unclear what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\#\{X_n\in [a, b]\}}{n} = k\int_a^b\sin^2\theta d\theta \ \ where \ \color{red}{k=\frac{2}{\pi}}\tag{1}$$

Please note that I have added a factor $k=\color{red}{\frac{2}{\pi}}$. See later.

First of all, as the values taken by the LHS of (1) are between $0$ and $1$, the same must be true for the RHS of (1).

**This is why I have added factor $k$** in order that

$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin^2\theta d\theta = 1.$$

Let $f_X$ and $F_X$ be the pdf and cdf resp. of random variable $X$.

The LHS of (1) is plainly $\int_a^b f_X(x)dx$ under the classical "subjectivist" assumptions of probability (I think that the error term $O(\log(n)/n)$ comes from a theorem of De Finetti, not sure, but we don't need it ; I would even say that I find its presence a little strange).

Therefore, if identity (1) is valid for any $a,b$, they define a same measure ; therefore:

$$f_X(x)=k \sin^2(x)=k\frac12(1-\cos(2x))=\frac{1}{\pi}(1-\cos(2x))$$

giving, by integration:

$$F_X(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{for} \ x<0\\ \frac{1}{\pi}(\frac12 x- \frac14 \sin(2x)) & \text{for} \ x \in [0, \pi]\\ 1&\text{for} \ x > \pi\end{cases}$$

Let $Y:=\cos^2 X$.

Let us compute the cdf of $Y$ which can take values $y \in [0,1]$.

$$F_Y(y)=P(Y<y)=P(-\sqrt{y}<\cos X<\sqrt{y})=2 P(\cos X < \sqrt{y})$$

(last equality by symmetry of the pdf of $X$ wrt $\pi/2$)

$$F_Y(y)=2 P(X < \underbrace{\cos^{-1}(\sqrt{y})}_c)=2 F_X(c)$$

$$F_Y(y)=2 \frac{1}{\pi}[\frac12 c- \frac14 \sin(2c)]\tag{2}$$

It remains to express (2) in a simpler form, and finally to take the derivative of cdf $F_Y$ with respect to $y$ in order to get the pdf $f_Y$.

Comment: You haven't made any comment to my solution...